# Drawing customized graphs in Windows Phone 8.1 apps

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

Can we use `WinRT XAML Toolkit` to draw customized graphs in `Windows Phone 8.1` apps?

I am trying to find out a tool or a authorized set of APIs to draw charts which can be customized during real time by retrieving data from a database.

http://www.telerik.com/…/w…/overview/all-controls/chart.aspx was given as an option but I think u have to pay for it.

I am looking for a free option.

Comment: Can anyone suggest any good resources and tutorials which teach you to build customized graphs in Windows Phone 8.1 apps? I have been searching inside out but still I could not find such a resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can use the WinRTToolkit, they even have a [Nuget package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/winrtxamltoolkit.windowsphone) specific for Windows Phone 8.1, more info on their [CodePlex](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/)